# Bootstrap datetimepicker - can't get events fired

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have a pair of bootstrap datetimepickers. I need to catch date selection and perform some tasks.

The problem I am facing is one method fires as soon as I click the calendar icon, not even having selected a date yet. With few other functions I tried (to prevent previous behavior), they don't even get fired.

Not sure what I am doing wrong here:

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <div class="font-bold-small">End Date</div>
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm date" id="dtEndDate" data-target-input="nearest">
        <input id="tbEndDate" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm datetimepicker-input" data-target="#dtEndDate" />
        <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#dtEndDate" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery/Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ....
    var today = moment();
    startDate = today;
    endDate = today;
    bindStartDateCalendar(today, moment().add(1, 'years'));
    bindEndDateCalendar(today, moment().add(-1, 'years'));
});

function bindEndDateCalendar(d, minDate) {
    $('#dtEndDate').unbind();

    $('#dtEndDate').datetimepicker({
        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
        useCurrent: false,
        //showOn: 'both',
        minDate: minDate
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {  // <--- Not Fired when date is selected
              ...
        }   
    });
    $("#dtEndDate").on("dp.change", function (e) {   // <-- Also not fired
        ..
    });

    $("#dtEndDate").on("change.datetimepicker", function (e) { // <-- this does get fired but as soon as I click the icon
        ....
    });
```

Comment: do you use the latest version ? for me "dp.change" is working as expected

Comment: Does "change.datetimepicker" get fired as soon as I click the icon because I have set minDate? Also, when I comment out this function, onSelect and "dp.change" are not fired when a date is selected, why?

Comment: I commented out the minDate setting and it is still doing the same thing

Comment: I am using https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.0-alpha14/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js